# How do I latex the following diagram in the tikz-cd environment?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I am a little new to the tikz-cd commutative diagram package. How would I latex the following diagram in the tikz-cd environment?
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's good practice to try to do your own diagrams and ask for help where you are stuck. Otherwise you'll not learn anything.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 & & & H_n(X_{n+1},X_n) = 0 & \\
H_n(X_{n-1}) = 0 \ar[rd] & & H_n(X_{n+1})\cong H_n(X) \ar[ru] & & \\
 & H_n(X_n) \ar[ru,"i_n"] \ar[rd,"j_n"] & & & \\
H_n(X_{n+1},X_n) = 0 \ar[ru,"\partial_{n+1}"] \ar[rr,"d_{n+1}"] & & H_n(X_n,X_{n-1}) \ar[dr,"\partial_n"'] \ar[rr,"d_n"] & & H_{n-1}(X_{n-1},X_{n-2}) \\
 & & & H_{n-1}(X_{n-1}) \ar[ru,"j_{n-1}"'] & \\
 & & H_{n-1}(X_{n-2}) = 0 \ar[ru] & & \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Yes, I will try to next time. I was just completely clueless with this one.